# How do I know if a field can have NULL values or not?

Tags: sql-server, delphi

I have a table with a field that indicates it is not `nullable`. In Delphi when I do a `Select * from Table` and inspect this specific field I see the `Required` property is false, but I expect it to say True.  From my understanding `TField.Required` should reflect the Nullable property, but it seems not so in this particular case.

If TField.Required is not the right property to use how do I detect whether the field can be NULL or not?

Comment: Did you try to write the table's name and pressing ALT+F1 to show the table details?
There is "Nullable" column over there to describe if the column can contain NULL or not..

Comment: That is exactly what I did yes.  The Table explorer on the left with the fields on reflect the same too.

Comment: In many cases, the nullability of a field cannot be obtained from the meta-data of the database by the TTable internal code. Which database platform are you using?

Comment: @FreddieBell - MSSQL

Comment: That information is in the tags, @FreddieBell , the OP has tagged [[tag:sql-server]. (As I noted in my edit, it's not called "MSSQL" by the way, Frank).

Comment: You also haven't said exactly which component you are using. If you have a TADOQuery linked to a TADOConnection, then you can double-click the TADOQuery component at design-time to create a TField list, and verify that the required property was created at design-time. It is advisible then, to always create TField lists for datasets that are going to be edited by user.

Comment: @FreddieBell, I inspected these values at runtime using a TADOQuery yes.  I confirmed the same afterwards by doing exactly what you said, I filled a design time query with the fields with the same query as runtime just to test, and still it indicated NOT REQUIRED.  The table definition clearly says its NOT NULLABLE.

Answer (score 0):

Will be opening a case at Embarcaderro.  Have found the exact same issue now with a FireDac dataset where ADO dataset reports the field as Not Required, while the same is reported as Required by FireDac.